# Does Informatica Powercenter provide API to access session logs

Tags: api, logstash, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

Question - Does Informatica PowerCenter provide API to access session logs - I believe No but wanted to through in forum to be sure?

Objective -Actually I want to extract session logs and process them through Logstash and perform reactive analytics periodically.

Alternate - The same could be solved using Logstash input plugin for Informatica - but I did not find that either.

Usage - This will be used to determine common causes, analyze usage of cache at session level, throughput, and any performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Informatica Webservice's `getSessionLog`. Here's a sample blog post with details: http://www.kpipartners.com/blog/bid/157919/Accessing-Informatica-Web-Services-from-3rd-Party-Apps

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the correct answer i 'yes', since there is a command line tool to convert logfiles to txt or even xml format. 
The tool for session/workflow logs is called infacmd with the 'getsessionlog' argument. You can look it up in the help section of you powercenter clients or here: 
https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/5/IN_101_CommandReference_en.pdf
That has always been enough for my needs..

But there is more to look into: when you run this commandline tool (which is really a BAT file) a java.exe does the bulk of the processing in a sub-process. The jar files used by this process could potentially be utilized by somebody else directly, but I don't know if it has been documented anywhere publicly available....?

Perhaps someone else knows the answer to that.